# Silverlight Custom Control and Databinding doesn't work properly in WP7

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, custom-controls

I'm trying to create my calendar control with databinding.

```
    public partial class Calendar : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime),
        typeof(Calendar), null);



        public object Date
        {
            get { return GetValue(DateProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(DateProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }

        public Calendar()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();
   DayText.Text = ((DateTime)Date).ToString("dd");
            MonthText.Text = ((DateTime)Date).ToString("MMM");
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Calendar_Loaded);
            this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(Calendar_Loaded);
        }


        void Calendar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DayText.Text = ((DateTime)Date).ToString("dd");
            MonthText.Text = ((DateTime)Date).ToString("MMM");

        }
    }
```

But When I create the listbox with this control, same calndar have the wrong date. I'm sure that the Date passed thorough databinding is correct but I don't understand why same calender show a different day (I'm noticed that is the day of a previous calendar control intance)

Thank you for supporting!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm ... where do we start? Here's a few things I've noticed:

- If you're using a dependency property, there's no need to call `OnPropertyChanged` from the `Date` property setter.
- The dependency property declares the type as `DateTime`, but your public exposed property is of type `object`, which then requires you to cast it elsewhere.
- If `Calendar_Loaded` is to be called in more situations than in response to the `Loaded` event (such as the `GotFocus` event, then I'd recommend that you call it something else, or create a method with a relevant name (e.g. UpdateDateParts) and call it from properly named separate event handlers.
- Using fixed format specifiers when processing date strings does not localize well.

In addition to that, I'd suggest that you could implement the user interface in a manner that supports databinding (and re-templating) by using bindings and exposing the date parts of the `Date` dependency property instead of manually updating the `Text` property of some text blocks/boxes in event handlers. In fact, if you derive from `Control` instead of `UserControl` then you can create and actuall lookless control that has it's user interface defined by a style in themes\generic.xaml that can be re-defined by users of your control.

As for why the date is incorrect in different instances of your calendar control, we'd need to see some of your XAML/code to see how the control is being used and initialized to be able to provide a better answer. However, I thought the above was worth putting in an Answer, instead of trying to say it in a Comment.